# How to get property attributes for EntityType using Olingo

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I'm building a java service that accesses OData information. I'm using olingo to parse all my returned json. If I pull the metadata I can see that my properties have custom attributes under all of my EntityTypes. I'm trying to access these attributes. I can currently access all the properties but all I can seem to get is the key, value pairs.

```
for(Entry<String, Object> prop : entry.getProperties().entrySet())
```

Steeping through in Eclipse I can see that the EntityType object has parsed these attributes and is storing them in a hashmap. Any idea how to get at this using Olingo? Last resort would be to side process the metadata xml again but I really really don't want to do that.

I've also seen in debugger that the call

```
entitySet.getEntityType().getProperty("createdBy")
```

contains a `SimpleProperty property` variable that contains all my attribute annotations. Again can't figure out how to get access (both hacking and googleing). sigh :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with the guys on the olingo user group I have a solution. The code snippet

```
entitySet.getEntityType().getProperty("createdBy")
```

Returns an EdmTyped object. This can be cast to a EdmProperty in which the annotations and attributes are available for lookup.

```
EdmProperty prop = (EdmProperty)entitySet.getEntityType().getProperty("createdBy")
for(EdmAnnotationAttribute attr : property.getAnnotations().getAnnotationAttributes())
{
    attr contains your info
}
```

I didn't try this earlier as when I looked in the debugger after casting to EdmProperty annotations variable was null. Lesson learned again and again, never assume. :)

Annotations are loaded at the time of the call to `prop.getAnnotations()`